# How can add max and mix value at the y axis?

Tags: matplotlib

The max and min value in the `df['close']`:

```
pmax,pmin = max(df['close']),min(df['close'])
pmax,pmin
(35.48, 19.37)
```

Draw the graph without max and min value at the y axis:

```
pmax,pmin = max(df['close']),min(df['close'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index,df['close'])
ax.set_ylim(pmin, pmax)
```

[image]

Draw the graph with max and min value at the y axis,but no middle ticks in the y axis:

```
pmax,pmin = max(df['close']),min(df['close'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index,df['close'])
ax.set_yticks([pmin,pmax])
ax.set_ylim(pmin, pmax)
```

[image]

How can get the below graph?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the specific values (pmin, pmax) to the yticks() using the `ax.get_yticks()`, adding the two values and then using `ax.set_yticks()` to set it. The example below with random values should show you how to achieve this.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'close':np.random.uniform(19, 36, 200)})
pmax,pmin = max(df['close']),min(df['close'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
ax.plot(df.index,df['close'])
ax.set_ylim(pmin, pmax)
ticks = np.append(ax.get_yticks(), [pmin,pmax])
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
```

[image]

Comment: Make it more simple:np.`append(ax.get_yticks(),(pmin,pmax))` or `np.append(ax.get_yticks(),[pmin,pmax])`.